# Java continue statement not allowed in anonymous inner class

Tags: java, continue

I am threading a time consuming for-loop and executing them inside N number of threads. A continue statement is throwing error

Getting the error "Continue cannot be used outside of a loop"

```
for (final Message m : messagelistholder.getMessage()) {
    Callable<Void> tasksToExecute = new Callable<Void>() {
        public Void call() {


            if (guidanceonly1 == true && !QuoteUtil.isECPQuote(list.get(0))) {
                String msg = "Message From " + m.getSource() + " when retrieving Guidance values: "
                        + m.getDescription();
                String lcladdStatusMessages = CommonUtil.getLoclizedMsg(
                        "PRCE_LNE_ITM_MSG_FRM_WHN_RETRVNG_GUIDNCE_VAL",
                        new String[]{m.getSource(), m.getDescription()}, msg);
                list.get(0).addStatusMessages("Info", lcladdStatusMessages);
            } else if ("Error".equalsIgnoreCase(m.getSeverity())) {
                if (m.getCode().indexOf("_NF") > 0) {
                    continue; // price not found due to private sku
                }
                if ("Eclipse".equalsIgnoreCase(m.getSource())) {
                    String msg1 = "Please check Sold To customer data. ";
                    String lcladdStatusMessages1 = CommonUtil
                            .getLoclizedMsg("PRCE_LNE_ITM_PLS_CHK_SLDTO_CUST_DTA", null, msg1);
                    String msg2 = "Discount information may not be returned from Optimus due to "
                            + m.getSeverity() + " From " + m.getSource() + " " + m.getDescription();
                    String lcladdStatusMessages2 = CommonUtil.getLoclizedMsg(
                            "PRCE_LNE_ITM_DSCNT_INFO_MNT_RTRND_FRM_OPTMS_DUETO_FRM",
                            new String[]{m.getSeverity(), m.getSource(), m.getDescription()}, msg2);
                    list.get(0).addStatusMessages(m.getSeverity(),
                            (m.getDescription().contains("MDCP") ? lcladdStatusMessages1 : "")
                                    + lcladdStatusMessages2);
                } else {

                    if (response1.getItems() == null) {
                        String lcladdStatusMessages = CommonUtil.getLoclizedMsg("PRCE_LNE_ITM_OPTMS_ERR",
                                new String[]{m.getSource(), m.getDescription()}, m.getDescription());
                        list.get(0).addStatusMessages("Error", lcladdStatusMessages);
                        list.get(0).setOptimusError(true);
                    } else {
                        if (!QuoteUtil.isECPQuote(list.get(0))) {
                            String lcladdStatusMessages = CommonUtil.getLoclizedMsg(
                                    "PRCE_LNE_ITM_MSG_FRM_WHN_RETRVNG_GUIDNCE_VAL",
                                    new String[]{m.getSource(), m.getDescription()},
                                    "Message From " + m.getSource() + " " + m.getDescription());

                            list.get(0).addStatusMessages("Info", lcladdStatusMessages);
                            list.get(0).setOptimusError(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (list.get(0).getFlags().get(QtFlagType.ESCALATIONFORPARTNER) != null) {
                list.get(0).getFlags().get(QtFlagType.ESCALATIONFORPARTNER).setFlgVl(null);
            }
            if (m.getCode() != null) {
                String pricingServiceMsgCode = m.getCode();
                String pricingServiceSeverity = m.getSeverity();
                Map<Integer, AutoEscalationScenario> categoryMap;

                if (StringUtils.equals("ERROR", pricingServiceSeverity)) {
                    categoryMap = getScenario("SEVERITY", globalAccount1, null, true, null);
                    if (categoryMap.size() != 0) {
                        finalCategorylist.get(0).putAll(categoryMap);
                    }
                }
                if (partnerExclusivityAutoEscalation1) {
                    categoryMap = getScenario(pricingServiceMsgCode, globalAccount1, null, true, null);
                    if (categoryMap != null && categoryMap.size() != 0) {
                        finalCategorylist.get(0).putAll(categoryMap);
                    }
                }
            }


            return null;
        }

    };
    runnableTasks.add(tasksToExecute);
}
```

Can someone help me to skip the particular loop for the speicified condition but without using continue statement since it throws error.

Comment: Please, indent your code so we can read it without horizontal scrolling

Comment: The `continue` statement is not "inside" the `for` loop.  It's in the body of a method of an anonymous inner class.  Although the inner class is nested within the `for` loop, its `call()` method is compiled as a separate function.

Comment: I removed [multithreading] and [java-threads] tags from this question because nothing in the example code or in the question text has anything to do with threads.  The code snippet builds a list of `Callable` instances, but what the program will do with that list is (a) not shown, and (b) not relevant to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that you are actually calling continue outside of a loop  because the call() function itself does not have a for loop, so it doesn't matter if are only calling call() from a loop.
 What can you do to fix this is making the call function to return a boolean and replacing the continues with return true and return false if no return true has been reached. 
Then replace the:

```
 call()
```

on the loop(s) for

```
if(call()) continue
```

Answer (score 0):

So the I'm not saying I fully understand you code, but it appears that you are using `continue` to break out of that thread. On a normal multi-threaded application, it looks like you are launching multiple threads from one one loop. The `continue` call is inside the new thread, not the loop. As soon as you start writing the `call()` method, you leave the loop to run it. Looking at the code, I would try replacing `continue` with `return`. Normally I would try running it myself before I suggest it, but without the rest of the code I cannot verify that it works.

Comment: There are no threads shown in the OP's code fragment. We have no way to know what `runnableTasks` is, but it seems like it might be a `List`. If that's the case, then the OP's `for` loop iterates over a sequence of messages, and for each one, it creates a new `Callable` instance, and adds the new instance to a list.  We don't know what the program will go on to do with that list.

Comment: Sort of, except for in the question he said he was threading a for loop to run 'N' number of threads.

Comment: Yea but that's not pertinent to the problem. It doesn't matter what the OP wants to do with those `Callable` instances if the compiler won't accept the `call()` method definition.

Comment: It should work if you change `continue` to `return`, they should have the same impact on the `call()` method, correct?